# Circling special scatter plot points in Core Plot

Tags: objective-c, charts, core-plot, interpolation

I have a scatter plot where some points are interpolated and some points are the 'key' points used for those interpolations. I want the key points to stand out, by using a larger ellipse as a plot symbol. How do I do this in core plot?

I know how to make all points in the plot be represented as an ellipse:

```
CPTPlotSymbol *plotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
plotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor whiteColor]];
plotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0);
plot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;
```

But not how to filter that setting, like you can with text labels by implementing dataLabelForPlot:

```
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx {
    return isSpecial(idx) ? [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:@"key"] : nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:` datasource method. Return a special plot symbol at the key indices to highlight certain points. Return `nil` to use the default `plotSymbol` or `[NSNull null]` to skip drawing a symbol at the index.

Comment: That did it. Implementing `-(CPTPlotSymbol *)symbolForScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx` of `CPTScatterPlotDataSource`.